# combine two RGB images to a 6 channel image - openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working with a openCV and I need to combine two three channel RGB images into one 6 channel image.  I'm not sure exactly how I would go about combining them.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you will have to create a destination matrix.
`cv::Mat` allow to create images with up to [`CV_CN_MAX`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d1b/group__core__hal__interface.html#ga3de14a42631396fe0480be69d5d2363f) (512) channels.
For example `cv::Mat(cv::Size(640,480),CV_8UC(6))` is a 640x480 image with six 8-bit channels. More generally, given `s`
input, you can obtain an adapting destination matrix:

```
cv::Mat(s.size(), CV_MAKETYPE(s.depth(), 6))
```

See [Data types](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d1/d1b/group__core__hal__interface.html#amgrpc2d7863fca30ab6c7f7119bf757962dd) and [`cv::Mat` constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a75a97b1e4e55f380c172af58048a7cde).

You might want to use `Mat::convertTo` to ensure both your input images have the same format, then use [mixChannels](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga51d768c270a1cdd3497255017c4504be):

```
mixChannels(const Mat *     src,
    size_t      nsrcs,
    Mat *   dst,
    size_t      ndsts,
    const int *     fromTo,
    size_t      npairs 
)
```

The 2 source images need to be put into a container (remember that assigning a matrix just creates a new header, without copying the image buffer unless explicitly requested).

The last thing to do is to create a `from_to` vector with the channel mapping. Given s0 and s1 input images, and aiming to have the following mapping:

```
s0 red   -> 1st output channel
s0 green -> 2nd
s0 blue  -> 3rd
s1 red   -> 4th
s1 green -> 5th
s1 blue  -> 6th
```

The final code will be:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> s;
s.resize(2); //Or `push_back` your 2 input images
s[0] = ...   //1st input image
s[1] = ...   //2nd input image
auto d = cv::Mat(s[0].size(), CV_MAKETYPE(s[0].depth(), 6));

int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 3,3, 4,4, 5,5 };
cv::mixChannels(s.data(), s.size(), &d, 1, from_to, 6);
```

Comment: note that `from_to` should have `0,3` in it instead of `0,1`

Comment: Actually, it should be: `int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 3,3, 4,4, 5,5 };`, as the indices are counted incrementally through the arrays.

Answer (score -1):

[split](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=split#split) splits an image in an array of single channel images and [merge](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=split#void%20merge%28const%20Mat%2a%20mv,%20size_t%20count,%20OutputArray%20dst%29) puts them back together in any order. There is also mixchannels() which is a more efficenct but more complex combination of the two

In theory opencv works with any number of channels but I suspect many of the functions only work with 1 or 3 (ie grey or 'normal' color)

Comment: I was looking at using merge, but I was a bit confused as to how to pass in all the channels.

Comment: @ChrisMondiek - just a std::vector of cv::Mat. It's reference counted so you can just add them to a std::vector and it will handle the memery